Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 - how to fix?
I am having issues with running my project as whenever I run it I get an error:

What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':motion_sensors' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org/
BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The funny thing is that, if I remove everything that depends on :motion_sensors and remove the dependency, then run the app, and then undo and hot-reload, everything works as expected.
I have tried many different things, like:

flutter upgrade
pub upgrade
pub cache clean then pub upgrade
adding: android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true to the gradle.properties file

And several other of the common answers on google, but since it seems like an issue with motion_sensors itself can we do anything to fix this?
